# Best way to update aria-expanded attribute when using :focus-within

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility

I'm working on a combobox, and in doing so, I want to use the new `:focus-within` pseudo selector to manage displaying the expandable listbox that's associated with the combobox.

:focus-within is a great solution and works like a charm. The only problem I'm having is figuring out how to keep the `aria-expanded` attribute on the listbox updated. Because all of the hide/show functionality is happening in browser-land due to the pseudo-selector, I'm unsure of a hook I can use in Javascript to determine when the item is visible or not in order to update that property.

Is there an elegant solution anyone knows about? I'd hate to have to replicate the logic for focus/blur that :focus-within is handling right now just to update this attribute. I'm also concerned they may get out of sync. There any way to spy on an element with `:focus-within` or something like that?

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
.combobox-container:focus-within .list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="combobox-container">
  <div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="listbox" aria-haspopup="listbox">
     <label> Foo
       <input type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox" />
     </label>
  </div>
  <ul class="list" id="listbox" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!-- items for autocomplete. focusable anchors inside li tags. -->
    <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

[Accessibility guidelines for a combobox](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html)

Comment: Since you are using autocomplete, wouldn't you want to control the display of the listbox via javascript (rather than css)? Much like [this example](https://webkit.org/blog-files/aria1.0/combobox_with_live_region_status.html).

Answer (score 1):

[focus-within only has 84% browser coverage](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within)

For this reason that instantly makes your solution inaccessible as a lot of screen reader users still use `JAWs` with Internet Explorer.

Additionally you have the problem that while this works as a demo, in the real world an auto-complete list will be populated via AJAX or via a preloaded list that is filtered.

This means that the list will always be shown the second you focus the `<input>`, even when nothing has been typed into the combobox (which is not expected behaviour).

This is one of the few circumstances where relying solely on JavaScript is acceptable (with a fallback that the form can still be submitted without JavaScript).

Instead of trying to use `:focus-within` you can instead use JavaScript to toggle `aria-expanded="true"` when you return some suggestions and then use [standard CSS3 selectors](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20selectors) to show and hide the results.

The below example shows the CSS to achieve this. The `+` operator is the key, it is the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) that selects the next sibling within a parent element.

**CSS:** `.combobox-container div[aria-expanded="true"]+.list`

For the example below I have made it so that once you type more than 1 character into the box it will change the `aria-expanded` attribute to `true` (and back again if the input is empty) - this makes it feel more like a 'real world' example.

**Side note:** You do not need to add a `tabindex` to the `<ul>`, the expected behaviour is to tab directly to the first suggested item, I have removed that in the example below.

```js
//ignore this, this is my standard jQuery replacement for snippets
if(typeof $=="undefined"){!function(b,c,d,e,f){f=b['add'+e]
function i(a,d,i){for(d=(a&&a.nodeType?[a]:''+a===a?b.querySelectorAll(a):c),i=d.length;i--;c.unshift.call(this,d[i]));}
$=function(a){return /^f/.test(typeof a)?/in/.test(b.readyState)?setTimeout(function(){$(a);},9):a():new i(a);};$[d]=i[d]={on:function(a,b){return this.each(function(c){f?c['add'+e](a,b,false):c.attachEvent('on'+a,b)})},off:function(a,b){return this.each(function(c){f?c['remove'+e](a,b):c.detachEvent('on'+a,b)})},each:function(a,b){for(var c=this,d=0,e=c.length;d<e;++d){a.call(b||c[d],c[d],d,c)}
return c},splice:c.splice}}(document,[],'prototype','EventListener');var props=['add','remove','toggle','has'],maps=['add','remove','toggle','contains'];props.forEach(function(prop,index){$.prototype[prop+'Class']=function(a){return this.each(function(b){if(a){b.classList[maps[index]](a);}});};});$.prototype.hasClass=function(a){return this[0].classList.contains(a);};}
$.prototype.find=function(selector){return $(selector,this);};$.prototype.parent=function(){return(this.length==1)?$(this[0].parentNode):[];};$.prototype.findWithin=function(a){console.log("THIS IS",this[0],a);return this[0].getElementsByClassName(a);};$.prototype.first=function(){return $(this[0]);};$.prototype.focus=function(){return this[0].focus();};$.prototype.css=function(a,b){if(typeof(a)==='object'){for(var prop in a){this.each(function(c){c.style[prop]=a[prop];});}
return this;}else{return b===[]._?this[0].style[a]:this.each(function(c){c.style[a]=b;});}};$.prototype.text=function(a){return a===[]._?this[0].textContent:this.each(function(b){b.textContent=a;});};$.prototype.html=function(a){return a===[]._?this[0].innerHTML:this.each(function(b){b.innerHTML=a;});};$.prototype.attr=function(a,b){return b===[]._?this[0].getAttribute(a):this.each(function(c){c.setAttribute(a,b);});};$.param=function(obj,prefix){var str=[];for(var p in obj){var k=prefix?prefix+"["+p+"]":p,v=obj[p];str.push(typeof v=="object"?$.param(v,k):encodeURIComponent(k)+"="+encodeURIComponent(v));}
return str.join("&");};$.prototype.append=function(a){return this.each(function(b){b.appendChild(a[0]);});};$.ajax=function(a,b,c,d){var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();var type=(typeof(b)==='object')?1:0;var gp=['GET','POST'];xhr.open(gp[type],a,true);if(type==1){xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");}
xhr.responseType=(typeof(c)==='string')?c:'';var cb=(!type)?b:c;xhr.onerror=function(){cb(this,true);};xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState===4){if(this.status>=200&&this.status<400){cb(this,false);}else{cb(this,true);}}};if(type){xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');xhr.send($.param(b));}else{xhr.send();}
xhr=null;};

//only part of the demo, not for production use
$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
    if($(this)[0].value.length > 0){
        $('div[role=combobox]').attr('aria-expanded', true);
        return; 
    }
    $('div[role=combobox]').attr('aria-expanded', false);
    return;
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
.combobox-container div[aria-expanded="true"]+.list{
  display: block;
  border:2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<section class="combobox-container">
  <div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="listbox" aria-haspopup="listbox">
     <label> Foo
       <input type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox" />
     </label>
  </div>
  <ul class="list" id="listbox" role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!-- items for autocomplete. focusable anchors inside li tags. -->
    <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```